# IIS7 Stop all website batch file

Tags: batch-file, iis-7

I have multiple site on IIS. 
I want to stop all of them with a batch file.

Raison : I have a program that create new site. But I got port conflict because on the creation the site try to start on the same port than another site. I can't tell my new site to not autoStart. The best way would be a little code for a batch file, that stop any website, without knowing their names. With that, at the end, my new site will be started and every other will be stopped.

maybe the Appcmd command could work (http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles-tutorials/windows-server-2008/Configuring-IIS-7-command-line-Appcmdexe-Part1.html)

I dont know how to use the List and stop command (for each in List Stop). If somebody know how to do it in script? Or maybe there's another command.

I need to do it in batch file.

Comment: Have you considered using host headers for the web sites? [Configure a Host Header for a Web Site (IIS 7)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753195%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).

Comment: for this one, I cant, because I add a new instance of an existing web site (another version of the site). I need to keep the old one.

Comment: I find what I want. desactivate AutoStart (appcmd list site /xml | appcmd set site /serverAutoStart:false /in) (http://blogs.iis.net/ksingla/archive/2007/06/17/things-you-can-do-by-piping-appcmd-commands.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

`Iisreset /stop` will stop all sites

Comment: so simple. Tank you. I need to start after adding my site. And I'm not sure why my site is started instead of any other.

Comment: its a "iisreset" not "iisreset /start".

Comment: finally, it was fake. I stop the server, do my thing, restart. its the last one on 80 port which start